# does netbeans support naming conventions for fields, parameters and local variables like eclipse

Tags: netbeans, naming-conventions, customization

eclipse supports naming conventions for fields, parameters and local variables. For each variable type it is possible to configure a list of prefix or suffix or both. eclipse respects this configuration when generating methods or getters/setters.
is there a similar configuration option in netbeans? is there another way to achieve the same thing: i want to get parameters with prefixes, when generating implementations for abstract methods and i want the prefix to be removed, when generating getters/setters (example: for _myVar it should generate getMyVar and setMyVar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to generate some feature you need like getter and setter and constructors and ... . when you change something you can use [re-factor](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring).

Comment: thanks, but thats not exactly what im looking for. i don't want to refactor afterwards, when generating an implementation for an abstract method to get all parameters prefixed with a "p" (for example: getTranslatedString(String pKey, Locale pLocale). Or rename the generated getters/setter for fMyVar from getFMyVar to getMyVar and setFMyVar to setMyVar. I was hoping, that i could teach NetBeans to regard my coding conventions and automatically add or remove my prefixes as  appropriate when generating code.